# Creating art by combining flexbox and grid but the boundary of my <body> div is cutting off part of the right column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out why my black grid lines on the right column (see pic) have been cut off, and I've narrowed it down to the `<body>` div using Chrome developer.

I can't work out how to move the boundaries of the body so that the lines aren't cut off, so that the full black lines will show.

My CSS is internal and sits within the  section of the HTML head.

Images:

[image]

[image]

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  gap: 9px;
  grid-template-columns: 220px 160px 130px 90px;
  grid-template-rows: 250px 130px 155px 65px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item grey1"></div>
  <div class="item grey2"></div>
  <div class="item grey3"></div>

  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item grey4"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item purple"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>

</div>
```

```
`<style>
body {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
display: grid;
height: 600px;
width: 600px;
gap: 9px;
grid-template-columns: 220px 160px 130px 90px;
grid-template-rows: 250px 130px 155px 65px;
background-color: black;
}

<body>

<div class="container">
   <div class="item blue"></div>
   <div class="item grey1"></div>
   <div class="item grey2"></div> 
   <div class="item grey3"></div>

   <div class="item yellow"></div>
   <div class="item grey4"></div>
   
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item purple"></div>
   <div class="item red"></div>
   
 </div>

</body>`
```

I have tried to adjust the alignment in the body i.e. `align-items`, and `justify-content`, but it hasn't had much effect. The black lines remain cut off and show as white regardless.

Comment: expected overflow issue. Use relative units instead to not cause an overflow...

Comment: you have all your values in fixed units PX. Container is 600px, and sum of column 220+160+130+90 = 600. So everything fine! No it's not. Fixed values with gap 9px. You have 4 cols, so 3 gaps add 9x3 = 27px to add to your container width, so 927px instead of 900px. Try, it works (do the equivalent for the height)